# How to get attribute in tag using SimpleXML

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml

I'm not sure of how to call what I want, so if you can provide any more accurate term, I'll update my question.

I'd like to get data from an XML site structured like this:

```
<body>
    <predictions>
        <message text="message"/>
    </predictions>
    <predictions>
        <direction title="Dir1">
            <prediction epochTime="1521560640000" seconds="724" minutes="12" isDeparture="true" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="paciland" vehicle="1606" block="22"/>
        </direction>
    </predictions>
</body>
```

I'd like to get the seconds (or minutes...) value.

I've found information about getting data from something structured like this:

```
<body>
    <predictions>
        <message text="message"/>
    </predictions>
    <predictions>
        <direction title="Dir1">
            <prediction>
                epochTime="1521560640000"
                seconds="724" 
                minutes="12" 
                isDeparture="true" 
                affectedByLayover="true" 
                dirTag="paciland" 
                vehicle="1606" 
                block="22"
            </prediction>
        </direction>
    </predictions>
</body>
```

Where data are not in the tag.

I've never used SimpleXML so I'm a bit confused about how to get that.

Comment: Are you asking how to get data from an attribute?

Comment: @Anthony it looks like it is what I want yes. Thanks for pointing the name.

Comment: Nah. Your answer is solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing attributes with simpleXML can be done using `$element['attribute_name']`.

Here is an example to get the `seconds` attribute from a `<prediction>` tag.

```
$xml = '<body>
    <predictions>
        <message text="message"/>
    </predictions>
    <predictions>
        <direction title="Dir1">
            <prediction epochTime="1521560640000" seconds="724" minutes="12" isDeparture="true" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="paciland" vehicle="1606" block="22"/>
        </direction>
    </predictions>
</body>';

$xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($xmlobj->predictions as $prediction) {
    if (isset($prediction->direction)) {
        echo $prediction->direction->prediction['minutes'];
        echo $prediction->direction->prediction['seconds'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I guess you saved me a bunch of time, plus that's very clear. 
Thanks to Anthony too.